# Is there an abstract ADO.NET interface that declares pagination?

Tags: sql, ado.net, pagination

I'm implementing a DAL library that is database vendor neutral. Is there an abstraction in ADO.NET (System.Data) for describing pagination? And, do some vendors' ADO.NET provider implementations support such an interface so that I don't have to manually tool up the customized SQL syntax?

Comment: I assume you want to do paging on a datagrid?

Comment: Not necessarily, but yes. I already know how to get the UI bits to paginate, though. What I'm shooting for is DB pagination (for performance sake). I also know the T-SQL syntax, PL-SQL syntax, etc., but I'm wondering if there's anything in ADO.NET that abstracts the declaration of a paginated query.

Comment: Why aren't you using an existing ORM?

Comment: Because the world needs more DAL libraries. A lot more. (j/k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADO.Net has no support for pagination. LINQ2SQL has, because the [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882968.aspx) and [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882788.aspx) operators are implemented by the SQL provider using the ROW_NUMBER() functions. Entity Framework supports [SKIP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738680.aspx) and [LIMIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738635.aspx) in its Entity-SQL syntax and also the LINQ operators for Linq2EF, see [How to: Page Through Query Results (Entity Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738702.aspx).

The LINQ2SQL methods are specific to SQL Server, however the EF methods are 'generic', as long as you're willing to use EF instead of the old ADO.Net methods.

Answer (score 1):

Paging is very platform-specific, because it requires you to retrieve the correct 'page' of data from the database.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is any SQL standard for retrieving those pages.

Comment: No I know there's no ANSI SQL standard for it because I know that each provider implements it differently at the SQL level. I was looking for ADO.NET abstraction, whether implemented or not.